# Reciting Boruch Dayan HaEmes on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, blessing, death, mourning-aveilus

If someone's parent dies, one must recite Boruch Dayan HaEmes. What happens if this occurs on Shabbos? Is the customary Boruch Dayan HaEmes recited or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bracha - Boruch ... Dayan HaEmes - is said on Shabbos. (Rokeiach Hilchos Aveilos 316 Minhagim, Shibolei HaLeket Hilchos Simchos 13, Tanya Siman 66, Sidur Bais Yaakov - Rabbi Yaakov Emdin, Chochmas Adam Klal 151 Siman 18)